# Is there any possibility to have LayoutNotFound Url specific to SXA site readily?

Tags: sxa

We have many SXA sites in our instance and want to configure each site to have its own 'LayoutNotFound' Url. Is there any ready configuration/field available with SXA like 'Page Not Found Url' field specific to Site.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this is to enter a relative url in the `LayoutNotFound` url setting. So `/errors/layout-not-found` and then create a convention that puts the layout not found page in the same place, with the same name for each site. Its not perfect, but it should give you the required results. If for some reason, you want a different Url per site, then you will have to implement a custom option for that.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at `LayoutNotFoundResolver` processor in the `HttpRequestBegin` pipeline (depending on your SXA version).

[image]

This is a custom SXA processor which at the moment should redirect you or transfer (base on  `Settings.RequestErrors.UseServerSideRedirect` setting) to 404 page (you can define it on your Settings item). Feel free to customize it so that you will be able to select a page base on the current site.